# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'Key' Encryption

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
cryptMode = input("[E]ncrypt|[D]ecrypt: ").upper()
if cryptMode not in ['E','D']:
    print("Error: mode is not Found!"); raise SystemExit
startMessage = input("Write the message: ").upper()
try:rotKey = int(input("Write the key: "))
except ValueError: print("Only numbers!"); raise SystemExit
def encryptDecrypt(alphabet,mode,message,Key,final = ""):
    for c in message:
        if mode == 'E': 
            final += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + Key)%(len(alphabet))]
        else: 
            final += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) - Key)%(len(alphabet))]
    return final
print("Final message:",encryptDecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage, rotKey))
```

Getting this error

print("Final message:",encryptDecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage, rotKey))
TypeError: encryptDecrypt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Key'\

Cannot understand what Im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

`def encryptDecrypt(alphabet,mode,message,Key,final = ""):` expects 4 arguments with a fifth optional.

You call it with only three: `encryptDecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage, rotKey)`, missing the `alphabet`.

Corrected:

`encryptDecrypt(alphabet, cryptMode, startMessage, rotKey)`

Comment: Now it says that                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      print("Final message:",encryptDecrypt(alphabet, cryptMode, startMessage, rotKey))
  File "Casesar.py", line 11, in encryptDecrypt
    final += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + Key)%(len(alphabet))]
ValueError: substring not found